# Why the server side variable is not getting bound to the .aspx textbox?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, public

```
    Public Class frmFMECA
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Public LastFailureDate As String
```

and using it like this in .aspx

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastFailureDate_GR" Text="<%= this.LastFailureDate %>" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

but it doesn't show that anything but <%= this.LastFailureDate %> inside the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a DataBinding Expression.

```
Text='<%# this.LastFailureDate %>'
```

And if the TextBox is not inside a GridView, Repeater etc you need to manually call `DataBind()` in the `Page_Load`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataBind();
}
```

Comment: it says that 'this' is not declared

Comment: alright. 'Me' worked becauss this is a C# reserved keyword and for vb it's Me

Comment: I don't know but somehow the databind() worked. I don't know why, can you explain what it is and how does it know?

Comment: If you do not call DataBind the values will not be bound to Controls. That is why when using a Repeater you call Repeater1.DataBind(). Reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.databind?view=netframework-4.8