# how to put <%=Request.QueryString["foo"]%>inside src attribute of html element

Tags: asp.net

I am new in asp.net webform, how to put value from query string and put it into src attribute of html.

like this

```
<iframe style="width: 100%; height: 300px;" id="irm1" src="Upload.aspx?id=1339" runat="server"></iframe>
```

to like this

```
 <iframe style="width: 100%; height: 300px;" id="irm1" src="Upload.aspx?id=<%=Request.QueryString["shipid"]%>" runat="server"></iframe>
```

please advice.

Comment: Remove the runat=server from the iframe if you do not need to access it from code behind.

Comment: When you add runat=server the iframe becomes a control. Then you would need a [databinding expresison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55933546/why-the-server-side-variable-is-not-getting-bound-to-the-aspx-textbox). That is why it works when removing it.